# Domain-Driven Design: How to Handle External Payment Gateway in Domain Layer?

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I'm designing a payment system that uses different gateways. I'm facing an architectural challenge when trying to adhere strictly to Domain-Driven Design principles:

I need to create a payment intent on the external gateway first.
Then, I want to create my internal PaymentIntent, which will contain the external gateway's payment intent as a child entity.
Before creating an external gateway payment intent, I have specific domain rules that need to be checked.

My dilemma:

**Injecting Services into Entities:** If I were to check these rules inside the entity, I'd need to inject the gateway service into the domain entity, which violates the principle of model purity.

**Always-Valid Domain Model:** If I first create the PaymentIntent and then set the external gateway payment intent, I violate the always-valid domain model principle.

**Domain Logic in Service:** Currently, I'm checking these rules in a domain service. However, I'm concerned this approach leaks domain logic.
Here's a simplified version of my code:

```js
export class PaymentIntentService {
  async create({
    marketplaceId, gateway, customerId, amount, 
    paymentMethodType, paymentSplitsData,
  }: CreatePaymentIntentParams) {
    checkRules(
      new TotalPaymentSplitsEqualsIntentAmountRule(amount, paymentSplitsData),
      new PaymentSplitReceiversMustBeUniqueRule(paymentSplitsData),
    );

    const externalGatewayPaymentIntent = await this.gatewayService.createPaymentIntent({
      amount, paymentMethodType, gatewayCustomerId,
    });

    const paymentIntent = PaymentIntent.create({
      paymentSplitsData, marketplaceId, customerId, amount,
      paymentMethodType, gateway, businessEntityId: '', 
      gatewayPaymentIntent: externalGatewayPaymentIntent,
    });

    await this.paymentIntentRepository.create(paymentIntent);
    return paymentIntent;
  }
}
```

How should I structure this to best adhere to DDD principles while ensuring proper domain logic encapsulation and always-valid state?

Answer (score 0):

Generalizing: we want to take some information from the domain model, and send it off to some external collaborator, and we want to take information received from some external collaborator, and pass it to our domain model.

In otherwords, you have a sort of *protocol* for moving information around.

In an idealized world, that protocol would be an *application* thing, not a *domain model* thing.  You domain model wouldn't need to know about it at all (beyond knowing how to produce and consume the information networked by the protocol).

---

In practice: that idealized world is difficult to realize in code when you face constraints like "our coders are not familiar with those idioms", or "LOL, WTF?"

So what you will normally see instead is that the domain model defines a "domain service" interface, and methods accept this interface as an argument, and our application implements some service that conforms to this interface, and passes it to the domain model as required.

---

Domain entities are clearly good at "tell me what you remember" and "integrate this information with what you remember" aka acting as a facade hiding its own data structures.  It's a lot less clear that they are good at "manipulating the world", and perhaps they are not supposed to be (SRP)?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! But I still find things unclear. I agree that domain shouldn’t know how external gateway works, but still, I want to validate domain model before making request external gateway. So the only way would be to pass the port to domain model, but I am not sure if that’s alright